# Removal of calcium from calcium-ammonium nitrate?

Tags: purification, fuel

I am interested in model rocketry, and need to produce small quantities of pottasium nitrate. For this process I need ammonium nitrate, but I only have calcium ammonium nitrate. Is there a simple process for removing the calcium?

Comment: decompose it at 210 C

Comment: You mean by electrolysis?

Comment: No I meant by heating.

Comment: Ah, so I would heat the compound (dissolved in water) to 210 C and then I should get calcium precipitate that I can filter out?

Comment: Yes, that would remove the calcium and give ammonium nitrate.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The rest of the internet wasn't very helpful, because most people associate ammonium nitrate with bombs, not rockets. I really appreciate it :)

Comment: If you add ammonium sulfate then the calcium will precipitate out and not waste as much of your nitrate content.

Comment: Why not just get potassium nitrate ?

Answer (score -2):

Soak it in water and decant off the aqueous solution freeze and the crystals should form its just calcium carbonate and ammonium nitrate
dont recommend using heat.