# distillation of aqueous CAN solution for the purpose of a reversible and strong endothermic reaction in cool packs

Tags: physical-chemistry, home-experiment, heat, applied-chemistry

I know calcium ammonium nitrate (CAN) is used for [cold packs](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/78776/in-a-reaction-between-calcium-ammonium-nitrate-or-urea-with-water-does-nitrogen). By bending a small metal plate the salt gets dissolved in water (separated pack) and this process is endothermic.

I would like to heat this calcium ammonium nitrate solution to get back anhydrous CAN. Is there a way I can do it without safety issues?

- [Source 1](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/66749/removal-of-calcium-from-calcium-ammonium-nitrate) advices to heat it up to 210 °C.
- [Source 2](http://www.azomures.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/FDS_CAN_EN.pdf) mentions the possibility to decompose at 60 °C into nitrogen oxides

Do you think I can heat the mixture up to 100 °C?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/78776/in-a-reaction-between-calcium-ammonium-nitrate-or-urea-with-water-does-nitrogen

Comment: Can I heat this icepack made of calcium ammonium nitrate up to get a reversible process? Are there alternatives with higher reaction enthalpy?

Comment: This is an extremely difficult problem. The answer is worth a _lot_ of money to people who would like to use this for something other than personal comfort cold pack.

Comment: What we think is irrelevant.  Try heating a very small amount to $100\pu{^\circ C}$ and see what happens.